# React, TypeScript Hero and TSLint question

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

I have created project in react and typescript in that one of the file I am using react router dom where in page I want to load component name dynamically from backend

```
<Router>
 <Switch>
  {routeData.map((route:any, key:number) => {
    return <Route key={key} path={route.PageURL} component={route.Component}</Route>
  })}
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

Now I need to import components like

```
import ListData from './ListData'
```

but it will go away when I save as those component are unused, how can I keep those component ignoring by **tslint and typescript hero extension** I want ignore only 1 file

Comment: what is setting `route.Component` to a valid component if the import is unused?

Comment: It is coming from backend I will pass Component name

Comment: a component name, like a string? that's not valid for `Route.component`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a string as the component isn't going to work.

If you really want dynamic routing like this, you could create a map of components that are allowed to be routed in this fashion.

```
import ListData from './ListData'

const routableComponents = {
  ListData,
  // other components that can be routed this way.
}
```

Now your route can lookup the actual component that it needs from the components you've imported:

```
<Route
  key={key}
  path={route.PageURL}
  component={routableComponents[route.Component]}
/>
```

Or, wherever you define `routeData` you could change that to:

```
// routeData.ts
import ListData from './ListData'

export default [
  { PageURL: 'url/to/list-data', Component: ListData },
]
```

Now this will work:

```
component={route.Component}
```

because `route.Component` points to a real component.

---

Lastly, leave off that `:any`! As long `routeData` comes from a typescript file, you don't want to be losing type info like that.

Comment: Ok I will try this

Comment: I updated my answer with a second approach that may also work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the way I would handle this, is in your components directory create a `index.ts` or `components.ts` file that looks like this:

```
import { ListData } from './ListData';
import { Component2 } from './Component2';

const components: React.Component<RouteComponentProps>[] = {
  ListData,
  Component2
};

export default components;
```

Then you could import these components in your app with:

```
import components from './components';
```

This will give you an object with its keys the component name, and values the component. You can then access a component as such: `components['ListData']`

Note: this is untested and my types might be wrong, I hope this is enough to send you on the right path.